# Txt.file does not want to open in Latex

Tags: bibliographies, errors, pdftex, symbols, packages

After not closing my Latex in the correct manner, while being open in txt.file, my txt.file did not want to open up again. You can open up all my other txt.files exept for the one I closed my Latex in.

All I am seeing is a blue screen when I am trying to open the txt.file in Latex. You can scroll through all the work, but there is not text. Latex also do not want to compile a pdf. Is the file corrupt?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. We cannot help you unless you provide more data. What's your operating system? Which LaTeX editor are you using? Besides, what has this to do with [tag:bibliographies], [tag:symbols], or [tag:packages]?

Comment: May be the file is locked by your operating system? Can you open it in an ordinary ASCII-editor? // If nothing helps, copy it with a different name. Either use the "new" file, or delete the "old" one and rename it. // Perhaps it helps to delete all .aux files. // It may also be a good idea to inspect the .log-file(s) beforehand.